# GGTS throwing error when building, string index out of range

Tags: eclipse, grails, build, spring-tool-suite

I am working on a very large project, and am currently tasked to get the project to work correctly using GGTS rather than intelli-j. The project compiles and runs correctly from cygwin. However, when trying to build the project in GGTS an error occurs. The error thrown is as follows:

**Errors occurred during the build.

Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'project'.

String index out of range: -23**

The error gets highlighted under a src/groovy package. specifically GGTS highlights the "p" in the following:

package com.bussiness.sys.rep

/*  CODE */

When looking at the error thrown at this point the following is said.

**The type org.joda.convert.FromString cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files**

I have tried multiple grails clean, refresh-dependencies, builds, looking into configuring the build path, and re-importing. I continue to get the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1:
Using Grails 2.3.8, and GGTS 3.6.0.M1 based on eclipse 4.4, for Windows.

Comment: hmm good ... try to clean ur mave using `grails mave clean`

Comment: should this be done in command-line or do you know if there is a way do that in GGTS?

Comment: Sounds like there might be a compiler error.  Can you look at your error log and post any relevant errors?

Comment: Also, it's likely that you don't have joda time on your classpath. Add it and see if that does anything.  The fact that an error marker was placed on the package statement doesn't necessarily mean that the error was caused there. It only means that that was the place where he compiler discovered the error.

Comment: I have tried to find the error log, but I can't seem to locate it within the GGTS directory. searching for error and log doesn't seem to bring up anything relevant.